# Create xml type output from controller codeigniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I tried this code to create xml file

```
public function get_markers()
{
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $sql = "select name, address, lat, lng, type from restaurant where status=1";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $config = array (
        'root'    => 'markers',
        'element' => 'marker',
        'newline' => "\n",
        'tab'     => "\t"
    );
    $xml = $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($query, $config);
    $this->output->set_content_type('text/xml');
    $this->output->set_output($xml); 
}
```

*This code return following result:*

```
<markers>
    <marker>
        <name>Soto Bangkong</name>
        <address>JL. Setiabudi No. 229 Srondol, Srondol Kulon</address>
        <lat>-7.06223759219975</lat>
        <lng>110.4129814497071</lng>
        <type>7</type>
    </marker>
    <marker>
        <name>Waroeng Semawis</name>
        <address>Jalan Gang Warung No. 50, Kauman</address>
        <lat>-6.974595476216744</lat>
        <lng>110.42663989422613</lng>
        <type>7</type>
    </marker>
</markers>
```

**How to make xml file from controller in codeignite**r, to add attribute inside node. To look exactly like this :

```
<markers>
<marker id="1" name="Billy Kwong" address="1/28 Macleay Street, Elizabeth Bay, NSW" lat="-33.869843" lng="-151.225769" type="restaurant"/>
<marker id="2" name="Love.Fish" address="580 Darling Street, Rozelle, NSW" lat="-33.861034" lng="151.171936" type="restaurant"/>
</markers>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    function get_report(){
    $this->load->model('my_model');
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('file');
    /* get the object   */
    $report = $this->my_model->index();
    /*  pass it to db utility function  */
    $new_report = $this->dbutil->xml_from_result($report);
    /*  Now use it to write file. write_file helper function will do it */
    write_file('xml_file.xml',$new_report);
    /*  Done    */
}
```

If you want to write csv file it is easy too.
Just use csv_from_result()  method of  and use write_file('csv_file.csv,$new_report).

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between xml element and attribute so you need to try this

```
public function display_xml()
    {
        $this->load->dbutil();
        $data = $this->db->query('select * from markers');

        $markers_data = $data->result_array();

        $this->output->set_content_type('text/xml');

        $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");

        // create root element
        $root = $dom->createElement("markers");
        $dom->appendChild($root);

        foreach ($markers_data as $value) 
        {
            // create child element
            $marker = $dom->createElement("marker");
            $root->appendChild($marker);

            // create attribute node
            $id = $dom->createAttribute("id");
            $marker->appendChild($id);

            // create attribute value node
            $priceValue = $dom->createTextNode($value['id']);
            $id->appendChild($priceValue);

            // create attribute node
            $name = $dom->createAttribute("name");
            $marker->appendChild($name);

            // create attribute value node
            $nameValue = $dom->createTextNode($value['name']);
            $name->appendChild($nameValue);

            // create attribute node
            $address = $dom->createAttribute("address");
            $marker->appendChild($address);

            // create attribute value node
            $addressValue = $dom->createTextNode($value['address']);
            $address->appendChild($addressValue);

            // create attribute node
            $lat = $dom->createAttribute("lat");
            $marker->appendChild($lat);

            // create attribute value node
            $latValue = $dom->createTextNode($value['lat']);
            $lat->appendChild($latValue);

            // create attribute node
            $lng = $dom->createAttribute("lng");
            $marker->appendChild($lng);

            // create attribute value node
            $lngValue = $dom->createTextNode($value['lng']);
            $lng->appendChild($lngValue);

            // create attribute node
            $type = $dom->createAttribute("type");
            $marker->appendChild($type);

            // create attribute value node
            $typeValue = $dom->createTextNode($value['type']);
            $type->appendChild($typeValue);
        }

        // save and display tree
        echo $dom->saveXML();
    }
```